# Why does Hibernate sometimes load instances of an incorrect subclass?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

we have a strange problem with hibernate we can't explain.

What we have:

1. one abstract class and two subclass of it. Let call them A, SubA1, SubA2
2. we have another abstract class and some subclasses. Let call B, SubB1, SubB2.
3. There is many-to-one relation between SubB1 and A.
4. The hibernate mappings for classes A and B look like:

   ```
   <hibernate-mapping>

     <class name="A" table="A" lazy="false">

       <id name="id" column="ID" type="java.lang.Integer">
         <generator class="org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator">
           <param name="segment_value">a</param>
         </generator>
       </id>

       <version name="olVersion" column="VERSION" type="integer" unsaved-value="negative" />

       <joined-subclass name="SubA1" table="SUB_A1" lazy="false">
         <key column="ID_A" foreign-key="FK_SUB_A1_A"/>
         <property name="p1" column="p1" length="255" unique="true"/>
         <property name="p2" column="p2" length="255" not-null="true" />
       </joined-subclass>

       <joined-subclass name="SubA2" table="SUB_A2" lazy="false">
         <key column="ID_A" foreign-key="FK_SUB_A2_A"/>
         <property name="p3" column="p3" length="255" not-null="true" unique="true" />
         <property name="p4" column="p4" length="4000" />
       </joined-subclass>

     </class>

   </hibernate-mapping>
   ```

and

```
<hibernate-mapping>

  <class name="B" table="B" lazy="false">

    <cache usage="read-write"/>

    <id name="id" column="ID" type="java.lang.Integer">
      <generator class="org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator">
        <param name="segment_value">b</param>
      </generator>
    </id>

    <version name="olVersion" column="VERSION" type="integer" unsaved-value="negative" />

    <joined-subclass name="SubB1" table="SUB_B1" lazy="false">
      <key column="ID_B" foreign-key="FK_SUB_B1_B"/>
      <many-to-one name="subA" column="ID_A" not-null="false" update="false" foreign-key="FK_SUB_B1" lazy="false" class="A"/>
    </joined-subclass>

  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Now the question: sometimes hibernate loads items of SubA2 as instances of SubA1 by loading items of SubB1, but not all items will casted wrong, only a few of them and everytime not the same items.

Maybe someone can explain, what is going wrong or what is wrong with our hibernate mappings.

Thank you in advance.

Ps.
This problem occurs for:

- JDK 1.7.71
- Oracle 12g
- Hibernate 3.6.10

I didn't try for other configuration.

Unfortunately, I don't have sample application, but I also can't give the source code of the real applicaton.

Comment: Can you specify your environment (versions of Hibernate, JDK, database)?  Also it would be nice to have complete sample app.

Comment: @sibnick  I added information about Hibernate, JDK and Database.

Comment: Is it you application multithreads, clustered? What type of second-level cache provider do you use? Can you  repeat bug without cache?

Comment: Shouldn't your Key column on the subclasses just be `<key column="ID">` without the `_A` (and `_B`)? Your Notation should generate columns called `ID_A`, which is not related to `ID`, except for the foreign key constraint. This would allow having 2 entries (in either table) reference a certain ID of `A`, which might be your problem. Can you add some example data? the `ID` should be unique throughout all (sub-)classes.

Comment: @sibnick yes, I can reproduce this bug with disabled second cache. We are using EHCache

Comment: @dognose i checked, all ids of all subclasses are unique

Comment: What is your threading model? Do you use JTA?

Comment: @Tima Can you run queries to verify that no entity is present in both sub-class tables? e.g.

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SUB_A1 INNER JOIN SUB_A2 ON SUB_A1.ID = SUB_A2.ID`

and

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SUB_A1 INNER JOIN SUB_A2 ON SUB_A1.ID_A = SUB_A2.ID_A`

Comment: have you tried to isolated the problem in a separate small maven project with a integration test? if it is so, can you put this on github or somewhere else? i think this could help to reproduce your problem to help you better...

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the problem using Oracle JDK 1.8.0_51 + Hibernate 3.6.10 + MySQL 5.6.26. Everything loaded correctly via `session.createCriteria(A.class).list()` and `session.createCriteria(B.class).list() ... b.getSubA()`. Not enough information to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

I think your hibernate mappings are right. So if you have errors I am sure it happens on casting time. I faced with this problem many times, and I always solved it using **Visitor Pattern**.

Another advantage of Visitor Pattern is that you don't need to force `lazy=false`, because it solves perfectly real type of a proxied object.

### How to solve your problem

I recommend you to create a `Visitor` class which implements two `visit` methods for every **A** concrete subclass:

- `void visit(SubA1 object)`
- `void visit(SubA2 object)`

The implementation of both methods is the code you want to execute when **A** instance is a **SubA1** or a **SubA2** concrete class. I put void return, but obviously you can change it.

On the other hand, **A** class has to add an abstract visit method `public abstract void visit(Visitor visitor);`. Once again, I put `void` return, but you have to adapt it to the return type of `visit` methods.

**SubA1** and **SubA2** has to implement this method as follows:

```
public void accept(Visitor visitor) {
    visitor.visit(this);
}
```

This way, when you run this code `objectA.accept(visitor)` Java has to resolve in runtime the real type of `objectA` without casting, and with no errors. It really works, I am using it for years with Hibernate 3.x and 4.x.

### Visitor Pattern documentation

Here you have a really nice article [Proxy Visitor Pattern](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/ProxyVisitorPattern) where you can find how to apply visitor pattern to hibernate when using proxied and non proxied objects.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Have you tried my answer to downvote? I am giving you the answer to your problem. That is a common problem I solved many times.

Comment: thank you for your answer. It wasn't me, who downvoted it. I will try the visitor pattern you suggested when i come back from vacation